# Building nginx From Source on Windows

Tags: nginx, build, mingw, build-process, msys

I'm trying to build nginx from source on Windows.  I got the following done:

1) Installed mingw, gcc, and msys

2) Downloaded the nginx source code

3) Ran the following in the msys console from the nginx source folder:

```
$ auto/configure --with-cc=gcc --without-http_rewrite_module --without-http_gzip_module
(output omitted)

$ make -f objs/Makefile
(output omitted)

$ make install -f objs/Makefile
(output omitted)
```

This produced the nginx.exe file in the objs folder, but when I tried to run it I get the following error:

```
$ nginx.exe
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: CreateFile() "/usr/local/nginx/logs/error.log" failed 
(3: The system cannot find the path specified)
2015/12/26 21:49:25 [emerg] 10200#9700: CreateFile() "/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf" failed 
(3: The system cannot find the path specified)
```

But when I run `ls /usr/local/nginx` I see that the `conf` and `logs` directories  are there, and the conf directory has some files in it:

```
$ ls -l conf
total 34
-rw-r--r-- 1 Admin Administrators 1077 Dec 26 21:30 fastcgi.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 Admin Administrators 1077 Dec 26 21:30 fastcgi.conf.default
-rw-r--r-- 1 Admin Administrators 1007 Dec 26 21:30 fastcgi_params
-rw-r--r-- 1 Admin Administrators 1007 Dec 26 21:30 fastcgi_params.default
-rw-r--r-- 1 Admin Administrators 2837 Dec 26 21:30 koi-utf
-rw-r--r-- 1 Admin Administrators 2223 Dec 26 21:30 koi-win
-rw-r--r-- 1 Admin Administrators 3957 Dec 26 21:30 mime.types
-rw-r--r-- 1 Admin Administrators 3957 Dec 26 21:30 mime.types.default
-rw-r--r-- 1 Admin Administrators 2656 Dec 26 21:30 nginx.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 Admin Administrators 2656 Dec 26 21:30 nginx.conf.default
-rw-r--r-- 1 Admin Administrators  636 Dec 26 21:30 scgi_params
-rw-r--r-- 1 Admin Administrators  636 Dec 26 21:30 scgi_params.default
-rw-r--r-- 1 Admin Administrators  664 Dec 26 21:30 uwsgi_params
-rw-r--r-- 1 Admin Administrators  664 Dec 26 21:30 uwsgi_params.default
-rw-r--r-- 1 Admin Administrators 3610 Dec 26 21:30 win-utf
```

I tried to run `$ chmod -R 0777 conf` but that did not seem to make a difference.

What am I doing wrong?  And how can I change it so that the logs and conf files will be searched in the local directory of nginx.exe and not in the `/usr/local/nginx folder` (which I found after some searching at `msys\1.0\local\nginx`)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try configure with empty `--prefix=` for dynamic path

> auto/configure --with-cc=gcc --without-http_rewrite_module
>   --without-http_gzip_module --prefix= --conf-path=conf/nginx.conf --pid-path=logs/nginx.pid --http-log-path=logs/access.log --error-log-path=logs/error.log